# How do I generate only a .d.ts from a single typescript file?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a single `.d.ts` file for a single `.ts` file without *also* creating a `.js` file(s) from my source `.ts` file(s).

I want to run something like:

```
$ tsc myFile.ts -d
```

But have the result be only `myFile.ts`'s generated `.d.ts` file.

Currently, the result is that that file and *all* of the `.ts` files in my project produce their own `.js` and `.d.ts` files.

My target is `es2015`, so the module option should be defaulting to CommonJS (if that matters).

Comment: Maybe include the `--noEmit` option?

Comment: @JeffMercado Then no declaration file is generated. :(

Comment: I used Shaun's `system` module solution he describes in his answer (at the bottom). It works well :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to create a single .d.ts file for a single .ts file without also creating a .js file(s) from my source .ts file(s).

While there is no compiler option for that, we can contain and delete the resultant .js files.

#### Case 1: A single .ts file that does not import local .ts files

What we can do is

1. assign `.` as the declaration directory,
2. assign `temp` as the JavaScript directory, and
3. delete the `temp` directory after transpiling.

   ```
   tsc --declaration --declarationDir . --outDir temp foo.ts
   rm -rf temp
   ```

That works if foo.ts does not import other, local .ts files. When foo.ts does import other, local .ts files, the compiler creates a separate .d.ts file for each. Since that is not what we want right now, what follows is better.

#### Case 2: A single .ts file that imports local .ts files

If our use case allows creating `system` or `amd` style declaration files, we can do this:

```
tsc foo.ts --outFile foo.js --declaration --module system
rm -rf foo.js
```

#### The Result in Both Cases

Both of those approaches generate the same directory structure with different declaration file syntax.

```
bar
  bar.ts
foo.d.ts           <---- a single declaration file
foo.ts
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: I get the second result using the first set of commands, unfortunately. It's almost like it doesn't care that I'm specifying `myFile.ts` at the end... :( Configuration issue maybe?

Comment: @KevinBeal Good to know. I will see if I can recreate your result. It *might* be that tscofig is overriding your command line options.

Comment: @KevinBeal What is your `tsc -v` output?

Comment: The version is 2.4.2

Comment: @KevinBeal I have tried using a `tscofig` with `"include": [ "./**/*" ]` and have not been able to recreate your result. Have you tried with a fresh `tsconfig` file?

Comment: I have also tried using the version 2.4.2 compiler.

Comment: I discovered that it works as you described when the source file has no imports from other local files. So, technically, without that detail, your answer perfectly addresses the issue as stated. Should I update the question you think? I'm not sure what the etiquette here is...

Comment: @KevinBeal Hmm. Actually, there is no need to update the question, because it is a reasonable assumption that the compiler will walk the dependency tree of the target file.

Comment: @KevinBeal What module system are you using? Common options are `commonjs`, `system`, and `amd`.

Comment: I'm using "commonjs"

Comment: No need for `rm -rf` in the second case if you add `--emitDeclarationOnly` to tsc command.

Comment: Works, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73416945/8186898) for a simple native and safe support

Answer (score 8):

Since the last accepted answer, TS has added support for [emitDeclarationOnly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#emitDeclarationOnly) that does just that

Example `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Example usage

```bash
npx tsc
```

Comment: Thanks !!! Writing a library using `vite`, this thing came as a relief. Otherwise, I would have to write it all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bundle `*.d.ts` in your project into one file, you can use `outFile` compiler option. Take note that you must have `emitDeclarationOnly` set to `true` so that typescript compiler won't be confused on how to transpile your code.

[About --outFile option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outFile)

```json
{
    compilerOptions: {
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        "outFile": <filename>
    }
}
```